# Make code shorter

Tags: jquery, dropzone.js

Hi is there other way to make this code shorter? I have multiple forms in one page so I need to target it by ID.

```
 $('#documents_valid_id .dz-remove').click(function(){
   $('#documents_valid_id').removeClass('doc-upload-error');
 });

 $('#documents_proof_billing .dz-remove').click(function(){
   $('#documents_proof_billing').removeClass('doc-upload-error');
 });

 $('#documents_proof_income .dz-remove').click(function(){
    $('#documents_proof_income').removeClass('doc-upload-error');
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

yes. you could use the common class `.dz-remove` to select the element, given that class is only applied to elements which you want remove the `doc-upload-error` class from.

you'll only need to do it once. like this:

```
 $('.dz-remove').click(function(){
   $(this).parent().removeClass('doc-upload-error');
 });
```

Or you could just add a custom class to any element which you want to remove that class from on your own and find it in jquery with `$('.class-name')`, then do the same thing you're doing now.

If you want to select `.dz-remove` inside those IDs only, you could still make it work like this:

```
$('#documents_valid_id .dz-remove, 
   #documents_proof_billing .dz-remove, 
   #documents_proof_income .dz-remove'
 ).click(function(){
   $(this).parent().removeClass('doc-upload-error');
 });
```

**NOTE:** this method would fail if your element containing `.dz-remove` class is not 1st level child of your form. meaning it would fail if your html looks like this:

```
<form id="document_valid_id">
    <ul>
        <li class="dz-remove">
.....
</form>
```

it'll be helpful if you could show your html too.

Answer (score 0):

Consider refactoring to keep your code [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself):

```
function bindUploadErrorRemovalClickEvent(id) {
    var elementWithId = $('#' + id);
    elementWithId.find('.dz-remove').on('click', function() {
        elementWithId.removeClass('doc-upload-error');
    });
}

bindUploadErrorRemovalClickEvent('documents_valid_id');
// ... and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this :

```
                $('.dz-remove').click(function(){
                     var id = $(this).attr("id");
                     $('#'+id).removeClass('doc-upload-error');
                });
```